# pygame.mixer.music.load(filename) does not release the file after the music has been loaded

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

I would like to have the pygame.mixer.music.load(filename) command release the file once the music has been uploaded.  Since it does not release the file, I can not delete the file.  I have attached a very simple program illustrating the problem.

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.mixer.init()

# load the music
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')

# loop the music
pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

# delete the music.mp3 file
if os.path.exists('music.mp3'):

    # when we get to this point, the file is still attached to the
    # pygame.mixer.music.load() command and can't be deleted.
    # how can I unlink pygame.mixer.music.load() and the file music.mp3
    # so that the file can be deleted?

    os.remove('music.mp3')
    # ERROR: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is 
    #                      being used by another process: 'music.mp3'
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Pygame.mixer.music streams the file, so you can't delete it. If you load the entire thing as a Sound you could play that and delete the associated file. But I don't think you can load an mp3 as a Sound.

Comment: Thank you.  Placing           pygame.mixer.music.unload()          before the os.remove('music.mp3')      llne of code solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Placing `pygame.mixer.music.unload()` before the `os.remove('music.mp3')` line of code solved the problem.